# Locate stack/heap variables in memory

Tags: memory, stack, reverse-engineering, computer-forensics, volatility

I am currently trying to hot patch programs (update code and data in the program memory, according to a released patch).

Assume that we can stop a running program, and do the patch. If the patch changes some data initialization or assignment values, how could we know where the variables are, like those in stack or heap?

---

Example:

Before patch:

```
void func() {
    int a = 1;
}
```

After patch:

```
void func() {
    int a = 2;
}
```

---

When patching, how could we know the location of `a` in the stack (or maybe not in the stack)?

Comment: I would suggest you patching the initialization instruction in this case; locating the variable in the stack is not reliable (compiler dependent; also there are some optimizations which can make things harder to deal with). Would this solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a lot of knowledge of how the compiler works, you *cannot* know a priori where these variables are stored, or even how they are represented.  Each compiler designer makes his own rules for how/where variables are stored.

You might be able to figure out for a specific compiled program, by inspecting the generated code.

Comment: If we know how one compiler works, how to get them from memory at runtime? Like memory forensics, we do not have to know a priori.

Comment: If you can inspect the object code with a reasonable debugger then you can obviously inspect the value of the variables with that same debugger.   This is pretty obvious.  I suggest you go learn how to write some assembler, and then learn how to use a debugger.  Then it will be obvious to you, too.